# Accessory type is overriding index click on table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When I tap on an index on the right, unless I click on the very right-most pixel, it activates the accessory button tap. How can I make the width of the accessory button smaller so taps don't override the index list?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.container = self.fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject
}
```

Perhaps this is conflicting:

```
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 42.5; // 85 x 85
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.4, 0.4);
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white:0.2, alpha:0.4).CGColor;
```

Comment: Add code where you are assigning accessory button, cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton`

Comment: Try `UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator`

Comment: Interesting, @Mrunal is correct that the DisclosureIndicator doesn't interfere in the way that the DetailButton does; if that is appropriate to the action triggered, as is the case for me, it solves the problem. I'd upvote this as an answer.